# Failure when trying to remotely connect to ActiveMQ server with Python

Tags: python, activemq-classic

I have a ActiveMQ server with hostname x and port y. I am trying to connect to the server remotely to add messages to the queue.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
import stomp

# Connect to the ActiveMQ server
conn = stomp.Connection([(x, y)])
conn.connect()

# Send a message to the queue
conn.send("/queue/test", "Hello World!")

# Disconnect from the ActiveMQ server
conn.disconnect()
```

However I am getting the following error when using stomp.Connection:

`ConnectFailedException:`

Are there extra setting that I have to update in order to allow remote connections?

Thanks in advance

I tried looking into the server settings but didn't see anything to change to allow all incoming connections.

Comment: Is your ActiveMQ instance actually listening on host `x` and port `y`?

Comment: How am I able to check if it's listening? Thanks for your response

Comment: You can look at the `transportConnectors` element in `bin/activemq.xml` and you should see something like: `<transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>`. You can also look at the log when the broker starts and you'll see something like: `INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://host:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600`